# Sony Vegas - Rendered file showing 30 FPS when project and render settings set to 60 FPS

Tags: file-formats, vegas-pro, rendering

Some I am trying to render a video at 60fps in Sony Vegas but when I check the properties of the rendered file, it shows 30fps. Details below:

**Original Clip frame rate:** 50fps
**Project settings:** See below

[image]

**Render Settings:** See below

[image]

Is anyone able to advise why this is happening?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: For starters, uncheck "Allow source to adjust frame rate" flag. Are you sure the source is 50p?

Comment: @RustyCore that was it for me, many thanks! Really weird, because I have not touched that particular setting ever, but after a big Vegas Pro 18 update it seems to have started taking effect on my renderings suddenly.